# GIMP copy & Paste not working well

Tags: gimp

i want to copy a texture into another but when i do it all becomes a solid color
First one is what i copy
Second is what gets pasted

[image: First one is what i copy Second is what gets pasted]

[image: First one is what i copy Second is what gets pasted]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Both your screenshots are identical.

Comment: Is the target image color-indexed (see title bar)?